# OSX 10.9 xdebug wrong phpize

Tags: php, macos, xdebug, osx-mavericks

Quick background.

- Running OSX Mavericks.
- Want to run xdebug in NetBeans
- Pear runs okay

xdebug stopped running after OSX upgrade. Tried to reinstall. During the install I get:

```
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20100412
Zend Module Api No:      20100525
Zend Extension Api No:   220100525
```

But in phpinfo:

```
PHP API 20121113
PHP Extension   20121212
Zend Extension  220121212
```

Best thing I can figure out (after hours of trawling through similar issues) is to make sure I am using the correct version of phpize.

which phpize returns:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin/phpize
```

whereis phpize returns:

```
/usr/bin/phpize
```

My question is in two parts:

Is the different PHP API Version likely to stop xdebug from running and; how can I make sure that I am using the correct version of phpize?

Answer (score 2):

A wrong API makes Xdebug to not even load, so yes, that is a problem.

To use the correct one, you will need to figure out which php binary you use in the first place. It is likely that if you use MAMP's php binary, its in the same directory as the phpize you need to use. The same for /usr/bin/phpize, which should match /usr/bin/php's API numbers. phpinfo() output might give you hints as to which PHP binary is being used.